# How to check for combination of column values in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code is throwing an error:

```
select * 
from inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
where 
    (IP.[Date], IP.Patient) not in (select EncounterDate, Patient 
                                    from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC
                                    join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this)
```

Error:

> non boolean expression where condition is expected

I am trying to find all the entries in inPersonMedChangeNotes where the combination of values is not in the tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records table. How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot use multiple columns for your `not in` clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a left join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
LEFT JOIN tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC ON IP.[Date] = VC.EncounterDate AND IP.Patient = VC.Patient
left join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this
WHERE VC.EncounterDate IS NULL
```

Comment: except you would probably want to limit the select to IP.* to match the desired output of the request

Comment: Here is what I ended up using: SELECT * 
FROM inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
LEFT JOIN tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC ON IP.[Date] = VC.EncounterDate
left join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this AND IP.Patient = PS.Name
WHERE PatientClinicVisitRecordsId_this is null 
and PatientId_this is null

Answer (score 1):

Following the same structure of your query, you can use `not exists`:

```
select * 
from inPersonMedChangeNotes IP
where not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records
                  where ip.patient = vc.patientid and
                        ip.[date] = vc.encounterdate
                 );
```

I don't think the `patient` table is needed for the query.

Comment: patient table is needed because ip.patient is a string and vc.patientid is an int

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) for that. In your case (untested):

```
select * 
from inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
LEFT JOIN (
          select EncounterDate, Patient 
          from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC 
          inner join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this
) V ON V.EncounterDate = IP.[Date] and IP.Patient = V.Patient 
where v.EncounterDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN query can check against only a single field, it cannot check against multiple fields at the same time. Check for each condition in a separate NOT IN clause and use an AND between them. Like this :

```
select * 
from inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
where 
    IP.[Date] not in (select EncounterDate
                                    from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC
                                    join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this)

And 


    IP.Patient not in (select Patient 
                                    from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VD
                                    join tbl_patients as PQ on VD.PatientId = PQ.PatientId_this)
```

Comment: I don't think this will accomplish what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

> First create function that will return EncounterDate, Patient then
>   use outer apply.  (if it works -:)  ) it will give you best
>   performance.

```
CREATE function spn ()
 RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
    (select EncounterDate, Patient 
          from tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records as VC
          join tbl_patients as PS on VC.PatientId = PS.PatientId_this)
         GO

    select *
    from inPersonMedChangeNotes as IP
    OUTER APPLY dbo.spn ()
```

Comment: you can also create trigger on database for alter table to track any columns change